# Conexión externa a postgres desde http php

Tags: php, postgresql, iis, windows-server-2012

Tengo mi base de datos postgres alojada en un server 2012 r2, también tengo alojada mi pagina web en el server 2012 r2 (iis).

Hice una prueba de conexión de mi php a postgres local y si sirve, pero cuando lo hago desde la web no tengo exito.

--conexión en mi hosting no funciona y en consola me sale:

```
GEThttp://34.125.155.251/conexion.php

[HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error 151ms]

EThttp://34.125.155.251/favicon.ico

[HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 0ms]
```

```
    <?php

    $conexion = pg_connect("host='34.125.155.251' port='5432' 

bname='postgres' user='postgres' password='1234'")or die('No se ha podido 
conectar: ' . pg_last_error());
    
    if(pg_last_error()){
        echo 'Conexion Fallida : ', pg_last_error();
        exit();
    }
```

---conexión en mi local funciona y no marca errores

```
    <?php

$conexion = pg_connect("host=localhost port=5432 dbname=postgres                     
 

user=postgres password=1234")or die('No se ha podido conectar: ' . 

pg_last_error());
    
    if(pg_last_error()){


        echo 'Conexion Fallida : ', pg_last_error();

        exit();
    }
?>
```

Ya configure el archivo `pg_hba`, le agregué:

```
host    all         all         0.0.0.0/0           md5
```

me funciona al conectame desde mi pgadmin en cualquer computadora.

Al archivo `postgresql`:

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

para conexiones externas, de igual manera ya configure las reglas del firewall
ya estan abiertos los puertos 80, 5432 , 8080.

En cuanto a los drivers no se cuales tengo que instalar.

Me pueden indicar que me falta por favor.

Comment: Muestra tu código de conexión y dinos si tienes errores y si los tienes, muéstralos en la pregunta. Dinos si verificaste que los drivers necesarios para la conexión están instalados en tu servidor, si estás usando las credenciales correctas (usuario, contraseña, puerto, etc). Pulsa en [edit] para completar la pregunta.

Comment: – A. Cedano ya corregí mi pregunta espero me pueda ayudar gracias

Comment: Ahí aparece un error 500. Son errores de servidor, por ejemplo si olvidas cerrar una línea de código PHP con `;`, por esa simpleza tendrías un error 500. Revisa pues en que archivo y línea ocurre ese error. Te ayudará revisar el log de errores. La conexión puede estar bien, pero si hay otro error no funcionará. Los errores 500 no tienen nada que ver con la conexión en sí, sino con la sintaxis y el contenido del código.

Comment: Aparece también un error 404, el cual refiere siempre a archivos no encontrados. Debes revisar los archivos que estás incluyendo y/o requiriendo, pues parece que no estás poniendo las rutas correctas. Los errores 404 tampoco tienen nada que ver con la conexión. Antes de preocuparte porque conecte debes resolver dos problemas previos que son el error 500 y el error 404. Una vez resuelto eso entonces podremos ver si la conexión está bien o no.

Comment: ya revise mi código y esta bien ami parecer, en cuanto al error 404 es raro por que si encuentra el archivo de hecho al código le agregue  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
 <h1>Conexion </h1>
<?php

 $conexion = pg_connect("host=34.125.155.251 port=5432 dbname=postgres user=postgres password=1234")or die('No se ha podido conectar: ' . pg_last_error());
 
 if(pg_last_error()){
  echo 'Conexion Fallida : ', pg_last_error();
  exit();
 }
?>
</body>
</html>

Comment: Si tienes un error `500` y un error `404` en el flujo de tu código nada va a funcionar. Debes por tanto resolver esos dos errores primero. Revisa la sintaxis de todos los archivos que intervienen en el flujo, para determinar dónde ocurren esos errores. Como ya dije, aunque el código de la conexión sea correcto, no funcionará  en medio de un error `500` o de un error `404`. Debes encontrar dónde ocurren dichos errores. Muchas veces no ocurren en el el mismo archivo, sino en otro que estás agregando con `require` o con `include`

Comment: en mi IIS me marca este error ;   El servicio de publicación World Wide Web (servicio WWW) no registró el prefijo de la dirección URL http://*:5432/ para el sitio 2. El sitio se ha deshabilitado. El campo de datos contiene el número de error.